# How do I backup and restore SMS Messages?

Tags: sms, backup, restore

How do I backup and restore SMS Messages?

Answer (score 24):

I highly recommend [SMS backup+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zegoggles.smssync).  It'll back up  your SMS to a Gmail Label:

> Automatically backup SMS, MMS and call log entries using a separate label in Gmail / Google Calendar. It is also possible to restore SMS and call log entries back to the phone (MMS not supported yet).

[image]

Comment: The forked version is in active development (original has had no changes since early 2010), and also supports backing up to any IMAP server

Comment: Very slow. I'm on a HSDPA connection, capable of youtube, skype etc. Still when restoring my sms'es it took about a second per piece, for each of my 2900 texts.

Comment: This program also stores all your data online in the Google Cloud, that is not a solution I would like to use (protection of privacy)

Comment: rubo77 it says you can specify another IMAP server... trying it now...

Answer (score 21):

You can use [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) to export to an XML file:

> Schedule automatic backups or backup your messages anytime you wish. 
>   You can view backup contents on your phone, and choose to backup selected conversations only.
>
> Backups are created in XML format and saved to your device's SD card.
>
> The XML can then be converted to other formats, and can also be viewed on a computer.
>
> It's easy to e-mail your backup files anywhere you wish.

[image]

Comment: SMS Backup+ also supports other IMAP servers

Comment: thumps up for back up in XML format

Comment: +1 for a solution that doesen't use Google servers

Comment: These days, this app defaults to backing up to one of several cloud services (including Google), but also supports backing up to a file. It still works, looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Use a 3rd party tool such as

- [Titanium backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/titanium-backup-%E2%98%85-root/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup)
- [Handcent](http://www.appbrain.com/app/handcent-sms/com.handcent.nextsms)
- ...

These offer many other options (such as backing up call log which I'd say is related)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [**VeryAndroid SMS Backup**](http://www.veryandroid.com/sms-backup.html). It is a smart Android SMS backup software that can copy and backup SMS on Android phone to computer, restore SMS backup file to any Android phone, and also send messages or chat with a friend on computer directly, exactly the same as that you do on your android phone.

It can help you:

- Copy and backup SMS from Android phone to computer.
- Restore SMS from CSV to Android phone any time.
- Send SMS & SMS Chat on computer directly.
- Transfer SMS to Android phone from other phones (iPhone, Windows Mobile, Nokia, Blackberry, etc).
- View SMS messages in threading mode on computer.

Answer (score 0):

Go SMS Pro https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jb.gosms has backing up SMS to SD as a feature. It is also a great replacement for text messages with Quick Replies and sending SMS on a schedule.