# How to migrate accounts and data from one Android phone to another?

Tags: nexus-one, htc-magic, data-transfer

I have a HTC Magic phone with Android 2.2.1 and I want to migrate all accounts (9), apps, sms, settings, etc... to a new phone with Nexus One.

Do you known some Android service/option or free app on Market to do it?

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE**

I have migrated successfully :)

Old phone: HTC Magic rooted with Android 2.2.1
New phone: Nexus One rooted with Android 2.3.3

- At first, backup google accounts with Titanium Backup Rooted
- Then, backup SMS and Call logs with Life Saver 2
- At end, restore in the new phone

Some problems with settings restore (Wifi, Bluetooth, apps, etc...).

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are rooted, use [Titanium Backup](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup).  You won't be able to restore some things, since the Nexus One and HTC Magic have some very different system apps, but most should carry over.  After backing up with TB, copy `/mnt/sdcard/titaniumbackup/` to your PC.  Then on the N1: install TB, copy the folder from your PC to the same location on the phone, then run TB and restore.

If you're not rooted, it's difficult to back up most things, especially all at once.  I'd rely on Google's backup for your list of apps and that sort of thing, as the other answer suggests.

Comment: Ah, beat me to it!  :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're syncing with Google already, most of that will automatically be synced to the new phone when you enable Google sync on it.

Comment: no : sms, app, settings, media files,...,  aren't synchronized at all

Comment: Yes, but I need to create all accounts at first on new phone. I want some like copy all > paste, or backup all > restore.

Comment: @tbruyelle: Apps synced to my phone when I switched.  It may depend on Android version; I moved from 2.2 to 2.3 (and was caught by surprise when it synced everything over).

Comment: @Lito: The problem with a copy/paste activity is that system (and system app, such as SMS) databases change between versions and there's no "upgrade settings" mechanism, so while there *are* ways to copy/paste settings and such over, you may have to do a full wipe to recover if something is too incompatible.

Comment: By the way, http://forum.xda-developer.com is a good place to find out about this, because it's probably the number one thing people worry about when flashing new ROMs.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't squeamish about rooting your phones you could use an app like Titanium Backup.

1. Just root both devices
2. Install Titanium Backup on both
3. Choose the apps you want from your Magic and back them up
4. Copy /mnt/sdcard/TitaniumBackup/ from your Magic to your Nexus One (this is the path used on my Droid, it may be different on your devices)
5. Load Titanium Backup on the Nexus One and load the backups

Answer (score 0):

For the SMS messages, see this previous question: [How do I backup and restore SMS Messages?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2466/how-do-i-backup-and-restore-sms-messages) out of the suggestions there, I've used [Life Saver 2](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.textuality.lifesaver2) successfully to transfer all of my SMS and call history between phones  very easily.