# How to migrate app configs from S2 to S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, sync, samsung-galaxy-s-3, data-transfer

I am asking this question because one similar to mine has been asked but it was specific to HTC rooted phone. Mine involves Samsung Galaxy S2 and S3. [Similar thread for HTC rooted phones](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7209/how-to-migrate-accounts-and-data-from-one-android-phone-to-another)

I have an external SD card, KeisAir on my PC and Galaxy S2 and Galaxy S3. Migrating contacts is easy, I need to migrate my app settings, sms messages, calendar entries ..etc.

As a note, I have disabled syncing to my Gmail account because I don't want my huge list of useless email contacts to sync to my phone. I have a samsung dive account and google (only Internet sync is enabled)

thanks for anyone who can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can decide what data you want to sync with google. In the accounts settings, you can disable contacts sync, and so only sync your calendar data, which would solve one of your items.

Concerning SMS, there are several Backup & Restore apps available on the market. The probably most popular one is [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore). Second item solved.

As for your apps settings, and "etc" -- that will get a bit more difficult. If your devices are both rooted, it could be done using [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup). Without root it's almost impossible -- except for those few apps using the Google Backup API (you can decide to have your "data" backed up to Google servers in your device's settings). As each app runs in its own sandbox, without root no other app can access its data.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting those apps. I installed SMS Backup & Restore, quite nice.