# Transfer SMS messages from Android to new Android phone

Tags: sms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I backup and restore SMS Messages?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2466/how-do-i-backup-and-restore-sms-messages)

Is there a way to easily transfer my SMS messages to my new phone if both are Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SMS Backup & Restore](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore&feature=search_result) (free and highly rated) in Market seems like a good fit for the task.  Backs up SMS to gmail (threaded), supports restore to SMS (hence the name).

Comment: Note that if you try to use send by email, Gmail on Android won't let you download the xml file