# Save txt messages to PC?

Tags: sms, backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I backup and restore SMS Messages?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2466/how-do-i-backup-and-restore-sms-messages)

Is it possible to move/backup txt/sms message from my phone to my PC?  I have Android 2.2  If this could be done via a usb cable, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Backup & Restore application on your mobile. Take the Backup of your messages only. Its going to store in SDCard/data/backup/.sbf.

You can copy this file into your PC using a Cable or using Bluetooth.

Anyways I prefer [SMS Backup+](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.zegoggles.smssync&hl=en) which syncs your SMS, Call Logs, etc with your gmail.

Comment: Thanks, is a .sbf file a text file which can be opened on a standard pc to see the messages?

Comment: It is not a txt file.Its a binary file. As far as I know there are some editors available to open this file.