# Save SMS to phone directly

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, sms, sim-card

Some of my text messages get saved in my SIM card automatically and this does not show up in notifications and I miss out on reading them.

I only realize the messages have arrived when I get a notification saying my SIM message

**inbox is full please delete messages.**

Is there a way to make the phone memory the default storage for text messages?

I am using ICS 4.0.4 in Intext Ibuddy Connect

Comment: Normally sms's are saved in your phone. Did you try clearing your sms inbox on your SIM?

Comment: Yes I clear it everyday deleting all the messages in the list....but after a few more incoming messages it comes back to full...

Comment: There are several apps in google play to backup SMS. you can use one of them.

Comment: Have a look on this link :

http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18194/how-do-i-save-sms-messages-e-g-to-sim

Comment: @ManishAndroid,Bishan Thanks both of you suggest me the same to use the SMS backup apps, but before using that I need to know whether I have received a SMS or not

**PS:** Please see the EDIT, Sorry if I was not clear with the question earlier.

Comment: Just a question, is the Intext Ibuddt Connect able to save SMS on the phone memory? Or does it save to the SIM card ONLY? I'm talking about the usual behavior for your tablet. Maybe it's like the old phones (like Nokia 3110) where the SMS are saved in the SIM, and not the phone.

Comment: @GreenGuy It does save messages to phone memory, but some of the messages are saved in SIM, those messages don't show up in notifications....

Comment: @SangeetMenon can you see any pattern in what messages are saved to the SIM and which are not? How have you deduced that they (the ones not showing up) are saved to the SIM and not the phone memory?

Comment: @bigbadonk420, All messages from no cellular devices (i.e. Service messages like bank messages etc.). But having said that they too are random not all of them end up in SIM.So am not sure of it as a pattern...
I realized it when my device gave me notification of SIM messages full and when I opened the SIM inbox to delete the messages, I found messages that I never read or got notified.

Comment: My shot in the dark idea would be that the following happens: Sometimes the device SMS storage is unavailable due to OS/SDcard/memory issue, the device falls back to writing to the SIM instead, and this same issue is causing notifications to not appear. I would highly recommend you to try reinstalling Android, maybe trying a custom ROM if your device is rooted in order to get up to a newer Android version (if applicable) -- or try another memory card if you are using SD and that might be causing the issue.