# How to transfer SMS message store to new phone which does not have an SD card

Tags: sms, data-transfer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I backup and restore SMS Messages?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2466/how-do-i-backup-and-restore-sms-messages)

There have been many duplicate questions asking about transferring SMS messages from one Android phone to another. The agreed answer recommended using SMS Backup & Restore.

However, it involves the use of an SD card.

My old HTC T-Mobile G2 has an SD card. The new Samsung Galaxy Nexus does not have an SD card slot.

Can I transfer the message store through USB mass storage on a computer? I have access to Windows, Mac and Linux boxes and will use whichever is easiest.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [SMS Backup+](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.zegoggles.smssync&hl=en). It syncs your sms messages with your gmail account and allows you to restore. If you have deleted the messages though, they are gone and if they are not already backed up then they are lost in the nothing for ever.

I have never use SMS Backup and Restore, but if this backs up to the sdcard, you should be able to pull them off the sdcard on your computer (using mass storage) and then transfer those backups to the galaxy nexus. If memory serves though, I don't think you can use Mass Storage on the nexus, it uses [MTP (Media Transfer Protocol)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol).

Comment: I *think* you can see the necessary files over USB if you switch the device from `media device (MTP)` mode to `camera (PTP)` mode. Do this by plugging in the device, pull down the notification bar and tap on the `Connected as a media device` notification and select `Camera (PTP)`