# How to save or back-up whole SMS threads on SIM

Tags: sms, backup

I have a Samsung-SGH -I927 and would need to save on my SIM card or send to my email for back up several text SMS messaging threads. I know that I can do this with an individual SMS' by lightly tapping on them and choose the save to SIM option, but I do not know how to do it with a whole thread. How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a good question, but previous questions may already have answers that will help you. Have you seen http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2466/how-do-i-backup-and-restore-sms-messages ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using '[Super Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idea.backup.smscontacts&hl=en)' utility. You'll get an option to backup your entire SMS threads on your SD card in xml file. You can easily restore your sms too.